# ASP.NET - Entity Framework Drop down List

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am in the process of learning how to work with Entity Framework with ASP.net. I was wondering if someone could explain the process or guide me to tutorial on how this is setup. I searched around but was not able to find anything.

I have 3 tables that I want the use to grab a result on a new page that meet all that creteria.

Example in modern terms:
Table 1: Mens, Womens, Boys, Girls
Table 2: Pants, Shirts, Underwear
Table 3: Nike, Under Armor, Louis

Suppose now on the home page we have a drop down that has 3 drop down list. If we choose "Mens" lets say they we dont have any invetory for Underwear, I want the second drop down to only show "Pants", and "Shirts". Now the third one will be only inventory that has is a mens pants, etc.

```
                <div id="Gender" class="select-default">
                    <select class="select-location" asp-items="ViewBag.Gender"><option>Choose Gender</option></select>
                </div>

                @* This will be the second drop down *@
                <div id="Type" class="select-default">
                    <select class="select-location" asp-items="ViewBag.Type"><option>Choose Type</option></select>
                </div>

                <div class="select-default">
                    <select class="select-location" asp-items="**ViewBag.Brand**"><option>Choose Brand</option></select>
                </div>
```

View Bag is what I am using but that is wrong cause that shows all brands, all types, all genders etc.

I thought I needed to do something like this on the first drop down:

```
                <div id="Gender" class="select-default">
                    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Gender)
                </div>
```

Comment: You populate your first select with Men's, Women's, Boys, Girls. When a user has chosen Men's, you use Ajax to call a method that takes in the Gender value (Men's) and gives back the categories for that gender. You populate the second select with those categories. User selects category, do the same but now you call a method that takes in a category (Pants) and you return the brands that correspond to that category. You use that to fill the third select. Then when a user chose the third item (Nike) you call a method that takes a Gender + Category + Brand and return all the products associated.

Comment: For Ajax I could just use like SignalR? I've used that before.

Comment: Of course, SignalR will be fine too.

Comment: @Dennis1679 Which would be most common/best practice to use?

Comment: I'd say go for SignalR if you are comfortable with that.